# await client.GetAsync returning NULL

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to send an `HttpClient` request to an API but the content of my response is consistently `NULL`. When I try to send the exact same GET request through Postman I see that data is indeed being returned.  Additionally, when I inspected the request from my app using Fiddler I also see that XML data is returned. Any ideas as to why I am seeing `NULL` when I set a breakpoint in VS?

Both the `response` variable and the `xml` variable in the code below are being set to `NULL` despite there being actual content returned from the GET request.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RunAsync().Wait();
}
static async Task RunAsync()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);

        var response = await client.GetAsync(urlParameters);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var xml = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var ds = new XmlSerializer(typeof(trainData), new XmlRootAttribute("ctatt"));
            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr))
                {
                    var trainData = (trainData)ds.Deserialize(xr);
                    Console.WriteLine("Station Name: {0}\nRoute Name: {1}\nArrival Time: {2}", trainData.stationName, trainData.routeName, trainData.arrTime);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There was an error!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are your url parameters. Can you share the baseurl ?

Comment: Yep... `private const string URL = "http://lapi.transitchicago.com/api/1.0/ttarrivals.aspx";
            private const string urlParameters = "?key=d94463bf32094ac6bb1417cd8f850a23&mapid=41300&max=1";`

Comment: What happens if you don't set .BaseUrl but just send a request using `await client.GetAsync(url);` where the `url` is the full url and not just the parameters?

Comment: @Pawel just tried that and I am still getting NULL

Comment: Unable to repro. `GetAsync` does not return `null` for me when I call that URL with those parameters.